# XOR Majority Algebraic Logic

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, boolean-logic, xor, boolean-expression

How do you implement a Majority function with XOR and AND only? [image] How do the authors of this paper get to the equation that they present below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Majority Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) with three inputs can be written as [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (product of sums)

> (a or b) and (a or c) and (b or c)

or as [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (sum of products)

> ab or ac or bc

Using AND and XOR, you can write

> maj(a,b,c) = ab xor bc xor ac

A truth-table is probably the easiest way to check this. An XOR with three inputs is true, if either one input is true or all three inputs.

```
             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
c     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Ok, so `(12*14⊕12*15⊕14*15)⊕18⊕other_two_registers` would be the equation if Bit 14 had not been negated with `true⊕14`, right? Now, to express the negation inside that majority-paranthesis, we add ⊕12⊕15, which I assume equals to (12*~14⊕12*15⊕~14*15), if you break the equations down to DNF/CNF... I should read into logical algebra again and try it out, tomorrow.